# How many Rows fetch from database

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-5

Have following code

```
   int Rows=4
   var result = dbContext.GetDistance(companyId).Skip((pageNo-1)*Rows).Take(Rows);
```

Question:How many rows fetch from database through above statement.?Is it fetch all rows then apply `Skip`? or  only 4 rows  fetch from database ?

Note:`GetDistance()` is store procedure having only `select` statement with one condition ..nothing else

Comment: Use profiler and you'll see actual query passed to database. But since it is stored procedure call - I suspect skipping took place at client side.

Comment: What's more, it will throw exception. Skip / Take at db side requires an ordered queryable (you need to use orderby before them).

Comment: @nopeflow thanks for reply .yes you are right but i have already added ordered query in storeproc .

Comment: @AndyKorneyev that means it fetches the all rows?

Comment: If all the methods in a chain are lazy (IQueryable), then the entire expression will be run server-side and only return necessary results. Whenever a method in a chain is eager (like ToList() or a method returning a List), the data until this moment in chain materializes in RAM (fetching all rows not filtered until now). In your case, it depends on the eagerness/laziness of GetDistance() method.
Replace GetDistance() with equivalent .Where() and it will for sure run server-side (fetching only 4 rows).